# Linq OrderBy issue when converting string to int with space

Tags: c#, linq

I want to order by `pincode` with string empty, when I am trying to convert `pincode` to an integer for sorting, I am getting an error.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Pincode { get; set; }
}

List<Student> objStudentList = new List<Student>();
objStudentList.Add(new Student() { Id = 1, Name = "gopi", City="Chennai", Pincode = "600002" });
objStudentList.Add(new Student() { Id = 2, Name = "ravi", City = "Bangulor", Pincode = "600 001" });
objStudentList.Add(new Student() { Id = 3, Name = "mani", City = "Madurai", Pincode = "600 007" });
objStudentList.Add(new Student() { Id = 4, Name = "anbu", City = "Thiruchi", Pincode = "600 005" });
objStudentList.Add(new Student() { Id = 4, Name = "kumar", City = "Thiruchi", Pincode = "" });


objStudentList = objStudentList.OrderBy(a => int.Parse(Regex.Replace(a.Pincode.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\t", ""), @"\t|\n|\r", ""))).ToList();
```

can anyone tell me what the problem at hand is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can avoid empty strings by first filtering them out. i.e.

```
objStudentList = objStudentList.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Pincode))
                               .OrderBy(a => int.Parse(a.Pincode)).ToList();
```

However, if you want to keep the `Student` objects that have an empty string but rather replace their `Pincode` property with `"0"` you can try this:

```
objStudentList = objStudentList.OrderBy(a => string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Pincode) ? int.Parse("0") : int.Parse(a.Pincode))
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: we need to remove space between the pincode numbers. eg: "600 001" remove space between 600 and 001.                        
I tried the below code, working fine, thanks for reply : )
 objStudentList = objStudentList.OrderBy(a => string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Pincode.Trim()) ? int.Parse("0") :
                int.Parse(Regex.Replace(a.Pincode.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\t", ""), @"\t|\n|\r", ""))).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you're trying to covert an empty string to int. If you want to get `0` as a result, you must replace `""` to `"0"`